# Amazon RDS stop instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am working on Amazon RDS, but I don't need instances to run all the day 24/7, as I'm only developing right now. Is there any way to stop an RDS instance when I don't need it? I don't want to pay what I don't use!

Comment: As pointed out below there is no "start/stop" your RDS instance. I would prefer to install mysql on an EC2 instance which you can start and stop even modify thru aws shell as needed.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is no "stop/start" actions for RDS databases, currently you'd have to terminate the database taking a final snapshot and restore from that snapshot.

UPDATE: Now supported (thanks @venkata-mutyala): https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/

Comment: Shame on Amazon, as of June 2016 there is still no such a feature)

Comment: @Green if you don't mind asking, why would you need it? A dns cname and a final snapshot would be quite equivalent...

Comment: @Julio - Stop button will be much easier

Comment: nearly at the end of 2016 and this feature is needed.

Comment: I would like to stop the master after promoting a read replica. To stop any writes to the master during the process... But still keep it close by in case I need to rollback the change (back to original master, abandoning the newly promoted instance for whatever reason.)

Comment: They recently added support: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/

Comment: RDS is now supporting stop/start feature : https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/, please add this to answer

Comment: amgohan he did, 16 days before your comment...

Comment: AWS SDK is your best bet but I am using TotalCloud.io to [start](https://usecases.totalcloud.io/use-cases/schedule-start-ec2-machine) and [stop](https://usecases.totalcloud.io/use-cases/schedule-stop-ec2-machine) instances under the free tier. Very customizable. Just replace EC2 to RDS in the template and it will work for you.

Easy to setup.