# How do I Start/Stop AWS RDS Instances using Boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds, rds

I had a question about Amazon RDS. I wanted to Start/Stop AWS RDS Instances at my need . AWS Console does not allow me to do so.

The Only method I know is to take a snapshot of the rds instance and delete it and when I need it then a create rds instance using that snapshot.
Is there any better way to acheive the same using Boto?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Amazon RDS stop instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326688/amazon-rds-stop-instance)

Comment: no, because there is no such a thing. you could terminate with a snapshot and create a new one later, that is almost the same thing, but currently there is no stop action in the RDS API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's probably the best you can do.  The RDS API does not support the Stop/Start functionality of EC2 instances.

Answer (score 3):

They recently added support: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/

Assuming you can use boto3...

Start:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.start_db_instance

Stop:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.stop_db_instance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just to add Venkata answer now you can start/stop instance using boto3. I created an aws lambda which start/stop my rds instances, using boto3 start_db_instance, stop_db_instance as the following:

Start instance:
    import boto3

```
def handler(event, context):
    rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = rds.start_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier='mydb-instance-name') #it should be rds instance NAME
```

Stop instance:

```
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
    rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = rds.stop_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier='mydb-instance-name') #it should be rds instance NAME
```

Don't forget, the parameter called DBInstanceIdentifier should be the rds instance name provided by you when you created it.

One important thing to remember is, you should provide a role to your lambdas, and if you want to start/stop rds you should set one role which has at least this permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can only start or stop AWS RDS instance of single availability zone instances. For your case, you will have to check if the multi-AZ option is enabled or disabled.

Incase your database is in Multiple availability zone, the best way would be to take the snapshot and restore it.